# PHP Notice: Undefined offset: 1 with array

Tags: php, ubuntu

I am getting this PHP error:

> **PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1**

```
preg_match('!select \'(.*)\' AS!s', $html, $matches);
$count = $matches[1];
echo "[+] Count: $count\n";

for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++)
{
    if ($count == 1)
    {
        $num = "0,1";
    }
    else
    {
        $num = "$i,1";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is no match in `$matches[1]` so the offset `1` is invalid!